# Enzyme mount not calling useEffect; react-testing-library render not calling useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, enzyme, react-testing-library

I'm trying out testing React hooks with Enzyme's mount.  It looks like the React hook useEffect is not being called.

This is my functional component:

```
export function HelloFetch() {
  type HelloData = { Message: any }
  const initialHelloData : HelloData = { Message: "" };
  const url = `https://localhost:1000/api/hello`;

  const [helloData, setHelloData] = useState(initialHelloData);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      url,
      {
        method: "GET"
      }
    )
    .then(res  => res.json() )
    .then(response => {
      setHelloData(response)
      console.log(response)
    })
     . catch(error => console.error(error));
  });

  return (
    <div>
        <div>
          <p>Fetch: </p>{helloData.Message}
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The api should return "hello, world", which it does in postman.  It also looks fine in the browser.

```
{"Message":"Hello, world"}
```

This is my test code:

```
describe('Hello', () => {
    const helloFetchComponent = mount(<HelloFetch />);

    it(' using fetch api should contain "Hello, world"', () => {
      expect(helloFetchComponent.html()).toContain("Hello, world");
    });
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Expected substring: "Hello, world"
Received string:    "<div><div><p>Fetch: </p></div></div>"
```

I tried testing it with the react-testing-library's render method.

```
test('renders hello world app', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(
    <HelloFetch />
  );

  expect(getByText('Hello')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

This is the error I get:

```
renders hello world app

    Unable to find an element with the text: Hello. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>
          Fetch:
        </p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I'm not sure what I missed.

Edit: Reposting my comments to @Florian here for better formatting.

I switched from fetch to axios. I have the following:

```
describe('Hello', () => { 
    it(' using axios should contain "mock Hello, world"', () => { 
        const mock = new MockAdapter(axios); 
        const mockData : HelloData = { Message: "mock Hello, world"}; 
        mock.onGet(helloUrl).reply(200, mockData); 
        let component = mount(<HelloAxios />); 
        expect(component.html()).toContain("mock Hello, world"); 
    }) 
})
```

The component doesn't contain data from the api even though the api is working correctly.

The following does work:

```
axios.get(helloUrl).then(function (response) { 
    expect(response.data.html()).toContain("mock Hello, world"); 
});
```

I don't know how to get `mount` working with `MockAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch is not available in Node, where Jest executes your tests.

You should not try to make real HTTP calls in your unit tests, you should mock them with Jest awesome tools : https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html

Or you could use https://github.com/jefflau/jest-fetch-mock too.

Mocking a function responsible for an API call :

```
import * as ModuleExportingAsyncFunction from 'ModuleExportingAsyncFunction'

const mockedThings = [{...}, {...}];

jest.spyOn(ModuleExportingAsyncFunction, 'getThingsReturnPromise').mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(mockedThings));

// no more real HTTP calls !
```

Comment: Thank you!  (I will write integration test making the real api call using selenium).

Comment: Exactly ! But if possible for you you should definitely consider using https://www.cypress.io/, you will save a lot of time (and maybe your mental health :)

Comment: I switched from fetch to axios.  I have the following: 

    `describe('Hello', () => {
       it(' using axios should contain "mock Hello, world"', () => {
          const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
          const mockData : HelloData = { Message: "mock Hello, world"};
          mock.onGet(helloUrl).reply(200, mockData);
          let component = mount(<HelloAxios />);
          expect(component.html()).toContain("mock Hello, world");
       })
    })`

The component doesn't contain data from the api even though the api is working correctly.

Comment: I don't know how to get `mount` working with `MockAdapter`

The following does work: 

      `axios.get(helloUrl).then(function (response) {
        expect(response.data.html()).toContain("mock Hello, world");
      });`

Comment: I updated my answer with pseudo code I use to mock HTTP calls. My services are exported functions returning promises, so I can import this module then mock one or several functions, and use Jest to return mocked data.

Comment: I found that if I use beforeEach to set up my MockAdapter and call mount, my test works!  Though I do not understand why.

Comment: this totally did not answer his question.